# outputted data to 6 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an exif reader to extract geo data from a photograph:`data.latitude = Number(exif.getTagDescription('GPSLatitude'));`I would like the answer to 6 decimal places, so that the output in the console reads 52.629147 instead of 52.62914722222222. Please tell me how to do this?

My question is different to [Round to at most 2 decimal places in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)
 because as a newby this question is not in the context of extracting integers - represented as values - from external media; rather it is just simple numbers.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the function below for you.

```
function roundMyNumber(n) {
    return n.toString().indexOf(".") != -1 ? n.toFixed(6) : n;
}
```

Take a look this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9a7oxgek/1/

I hope it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed(n)

(10/3)

- 3.3333333333333335

(10/3).toFixed(4)

- "3.3333"

This gets you a string, so you may need to convert it back.

Number((10/3).toFixed(4))

- 3.3333